# Why cannot save INT to SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-activity, save, int, sharedpreferences

I have a strange problem. I have never had it before. When I try to save int value to my SharedPreference and then restore in other Activity. Value is always 0 even if I save there other value (for example: 1);

```
private String Number;
private String Profile;
```

and then saving values (in this case "1") to SharedPreferences in first Activity:

```
SharedPreferences a = FirstActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("a", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorProfiles = a.edit();
prefsEditorProfiles.putInt(Profile, 1);
prefsEditorProfiles.putInt(Number, 1);
prefsEditorProfiles.commit();
```

then restore SharedPreferences in other Activity:

```
SharedPreferences a = SecondActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("a", MODE_PRIVATE);
int ab = a.getInt(Number, 0);
```

And application shows me 0 instead of 1. My other SharedPreferences works great. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: I assume you instantiate ``Number`` and ``Profile`` keys somewhere - and that they do match between Activities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd check what's the value of the Number and Profile variables you declared... you are using their values as keys, so if they have conflicting names, you might be overwriting one setting with the other even though the code looks right.

I'd recommend replacing this:

private String Number;
private String Profile;

With this:

private final String NUMBER = "Number";
private final String PROFILE = "Profile";

And then using those constants when setting/getting your preference value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works, thank you, but I don't know why when I use it before I didn't have this problem. Maybe because of that I had only one string in SharedPreferences, right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever set a value for 
"Number" and "Profile"? 
If not then that is your problem -those strings are null.

Comment: Yes, in first Activity when I press button, value should save to SharedPreferences as you can see in question (and then saving values (in this case "1") to SharedPreferences in first Activity:), but it doesn't because in second Activity when I display it with Toast, value is always 0 because of this (int ab = a.getInt(Number, 0);) if I change it to (int ab = a.getInt(Number, 1);) value will be always 1.

Comment: I mean - is there somewhere in your code where you set Number="Number"  - the variables you list in your code example are initialized, but not set. I am not talking about setting the SharedSettings.putInt(). I am talking about the variables you use as key values. Are they set?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

rather than using

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences ("PREFS_KEY", 0);
```

when Storing int in shared preference

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying for a while to use `putInt` like you but it always give an error.

```
prefsEditorProfiles.putInt(Number, 1);
```

by just changing `a.putInt` to `a.putString` and retrieving it with `a.getString` I was able to have the correct value.

so, I guess there should be something wrong with `putInt` and `getInt`.

Anyway, try that also to have the correct value you need to continue for application.