# share a int variable with sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a simple problem:
In first activity I save a variable as an int number:

```
valsat2= findViewById(R.id.valsatu);
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(valsat, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
int n = Integer.parseInt(valsat2.getText().toString());
editor.putInt(valsat, n);
editor.commit();
```

In second activity I'd like to use this int number, but if I use this code, it return to me 0:

```
public static final int valsat = 0 ;
TextView sat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoresaturazione);    
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valsat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int valsatn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valsat", 0);
sat.setText(Integer.toString(valsatn));
```

How can I solve? Thank you!

Comment: what is valsat ? in first code part of the question? is it a variable ? or typo??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cannot save INT to SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900226/why-cannot-save-int-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: Se my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

When you save the value to `SharedPreferences`, you use this:

```
editor.putInt(valsat, n);
```

So you use as key for this value the variable `valsat`, but what is its value? Is it `"valsat"`?
If it is then you should get the right value in the other activity but I guess it's not.
So change to this:

```
editor.putInt("valsat", n);
```

You also use the same variable for the `SharedPreferences` file name, but in the other activity you use again the string `"valsat"`.
These are 2 different things.
**Edit**
Don't use 2 Shared Preferences files. Use one with a name say "valsat":

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    valsat2= findViewById(R.id.valsatu);
    valbic2= findViewById(R.id.valbicu);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valsat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String n= valsat2.getText().toString();
            String m= valbic2.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("valsat", n);
            editor.putString("valbic", m);

            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

 public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
        TextView sat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoresaturazione);
        TextView bic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valorebicarbonati);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valsat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int valbicn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valbic", 0);
        int valsatn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valsat", 0);

        sat.setText(String.valueOf(valsatn));
        bic.setText(String.valueOf(valbicn));
    }
}
```

Comment: valsat is the name of a variable... an int number taked with ".getText().toString();" method from a EditText...

Comment: Did you change to `String.valueOf()` instaed of `Integer.toString()`?

Comment: Yes, I modify it; sat.setText(String.valueOf(valsatn)); but the error is the same...

Comment: In your code `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);` opens `Main3Activity` but the activity that gets the value is `Main5Activity`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, because after mainActivity, my app open Main3Activity (other questions) and then Main5Activity...

Comment: If you use only one name, like: `getSharedPreferences("valsat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and not others, then you have only 1 SharedPreferences fie. So the code should work.

Comment: With your method I send only a int variable number? But I need to send two int variables number ("valsat" and "valbic")? excuse my bad english!

Comment: One SharedPreferences file can contain as many values as you want. Each value has its own key. So the file "valsat" can have an integer value with key "valsat" and another one with key "valbic", and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value to "valsat" String tag. Change this part like this -

```
valsat2= findViewById(R.id.valsatu);
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(valsat, 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
 int n = Integer.parseInt(valsat2.getText().toString());
editor.putInt("valsat", n);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you included is clear that your code is attempting to cast an Integer to a String at SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(). If you use putString(), you need to retrieve the String with getString() before can you convert it to the type you want. You can't use putString() and then getInt().

```
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to 
java.lang.Integer at
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:272)
```

In the first code piece, you stored two strings.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valori", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("valsat", n);
editor.putString("valbic", m);
editor.commit();
```

In the second code piece, you used getInt():

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valori", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int valbicn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valbic",0);
int valsatn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valsat",0);
```

You should either store the String as an int (most likely what you want), or store and retrieve it as a String and then cast it to an int. The former method looks like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("valsat", Integer.parseInt(n));
editor.putInt("valbic", Integer.parseInt(m));
editor.apply();

...
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
int valbicn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valbic", 0);
int valsatn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valsat", 0);

sat.setText(String.valueOf(valsatn));
bic.setText(String.valueOf(valbicn));
```

The other method would be to store the String as a String and then convert it to an int:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("valsat", n);
editor.putString("valbic", m);
editor.apply();

...

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
int valbicn = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString("valbic", ""));
int valsatn = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString("valsat", ""));

sat.setText(String.valueOf(valsatn));
bic.setText(String.valueOf(valbicn));
```

Your original code and error message:

```
// activity 1
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    valsat2= findViewById(R.id.valsatu);
    valbic2= findViewById(R.id.valbicu);


    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valori", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(valbic, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String n= valsat2.getText().toString();
            String m= valbic2.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("valsat", n);
            editor.putString("valbic", m);

            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

// activity 2
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        TextView sat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoresaturazione);
        TextView bic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valorebicarbonati);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("valori", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int valbicn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valbic",0);
        int valsatn = sharedpreferences.getInt("valsat",0);

        sat.setText(String.valueOf(valsatn));
        bic.setText(String.valueOf(valbicn));
    }
}
```

With the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.osas, PID: 32694 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.osas/com.example.osas.Main5Activity}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) at
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:272) at
com.example.osas.Main5Activity.onCreate(Main5Activity.java:64) at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

You can find additional information here regarding SharedPreferences, including using getDefaultSharedPreferences(): [Why cannot save INT to SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900226/why-cannot-save-int-to-sharedpreferences)